# Button no longer functions Cookie Policy nav Window using Bootstrap 4.3.1 in ASP.NET Core MVC site

Tags: html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

After intergrating Bootstrap 4 to my ASP MVC Core web project and changing some HTML code to a Cookie Policy window. I noticed the accept button no longer functions. The button is there and you can click on it but it dosen't respond.

Besides changing some of the HTML for the cosmetic appearance the only other change made was the removal of a div tag which defined a container class for the text content. The JQuery code listed remains unchanged.

The function is called by a   tag located in the _Layout.cshtml file within the Visual Studio project. It was functioning before the change were made to the code.

Any positive insight would be helpful. Especially if there is something that I have missed or have out of alignment.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features

@{
    var consentFeature = Context.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
    var showBanner = !consentFeature?.CanTrack ?? false;
    var cookieString = consentFeature?.CreateConsentCookie();
}

@if (showBanner)
{
    <nav id="cookieConsent" class="navbar navbar-light fixed-bottom float-sm-left" 
         style="background-color:transparent" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cookieConsent .navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle cookie consent banner</span>
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <span class="navbar-brand"><span class="text-info" aria-hidden="false"></span></span>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="background-color:rgba(49, 67, 179, 0.80); color:lightgoldenrodyellow">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <h4><strong>COOKIE AND PRIVACY POLICY </strong></h4>
                        <p class="navbar-text" style="color:yellow">
                            This web site uses cookies and other technologgy for features and functions to
                            be viewed and operate normaly. You can acknowledge the site uses these features
                            by clicking the "Accept" button to the right of this message window. To view the
                            sites "Cookie and Privacy" policy page, click on the "Cookie and Privacy
                            Information" button.
                        </p>
                        <p class="navbar-text" style="color:whitesmoke">
                            NOTE: Clicking on the "Accpt" button only acknowledges you have read this
                            this message and is not a condition for access to this site.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                <div class="nav-container float-right">
                    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">Cookie and Privacy Information</a>                  
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light navbar-btn" data-cookie-string="@cookieString">Accept</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </nav>
    <script>
        (function () {
            document.querySelector("#cookieConsent button[data-cookie-string]").addEventListener("click", function (el) {
                document.cookie = el.target.dataset.cookieString;
                document.querySelector("#cookieConsent").classList.add("hidden");
            }, false);
        })();
    </script>
}
```

Comment: With your question, your code and the answer of Xueli Chen below, I was able to bring the consent to work with BS4 again. So thanks to both...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding `hidden` class is failed . If you want to hide the cookieConsent nav after clicking accept button , you could try the following two approaches :

1. add some css for the class "hidden" in the path `wwwroot/css/site.css` , the JQuery code listed remains unchanged.

   ```
   .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
   ```
2. change the JQuery like below :

   ```
   document.querySelector("#cookieConsent").setAttribute("hidden","true");
   ```

Comment: I have changed the code as suggested, but it did not resolve the issue. However, I did obtain new information. The casserole does not initially start to work, until I click on one of the indicators or move it to the next slide in which after this action it will start working on it's own. I'm wondering if there is another factor which is causing the code to react this way.